# On AWS RDS, Is there a setting to prevent malicious deletion of snapshots or backups?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-rds

As in, even if a malicious user gains access to my AWS account, I'd like to find a way to guarantee that at least one of the database, snapshots, or automated backups cannot be deleted by that user. Open to any method that accomplishes this. Thanks!

Comment: Not if they get access to your admin account.   They can add back any permission that you take away from it.  You can have CloudWatch send out email or SMS alerts about IAM policy changes but admin is zombo.com, anything is possible.  You can do anything you want.  Anything at all.

Comment: Maybe off-site backup to Azure or Google Cloud, then they need to steal 2 admin accounts from you.

Comment: the problem is, these backups or snapshots are stored in amazon owned s3 buckets. you cant see or download the backups/snapshot. therefore it cannot be copied to anywhere

Comment: If AWS has no APIs for copying those snapshots then a job running mysqldump or similar  is needed. to write to storage that a backup script can copy to Azure or Google.

Answer (score 0):

The safest option would be to limit which users in your AWS Account have permission to delete snapshots (and even delete the database).

This way, if an IAM User login is compromised, they hopefully won't have permission to do damage.

The "correct" answer, however, is to **use [Multi-Factor authentication](https://aws.amazon.com/iam/features/mfa/) so that an unauthorised user cannot gain access to your AWS Account.**

However, if your definition of "malicious user" includes a trusted staff member who might have become "bad", then this is more difficult. The general rule is to **only give people the access that is necessary for their job**. If their job includes the ability to delete Snapshots, then it is quite hard to take away this access.

Some companies copy critical data to another AWS account, and very few people are given access to *both* accounts. That way, there is a 'backup' of the data or configuration that one person cannot (accidentally or intentionally) destroy.

Comment: Good suggestion for a second AWS account instead of using Google or Azure.  Data transfer might be faster, and the second account will use the same AWS code, console, etc. that a person is already familiar with.  Least privilege and MFA too of course, but I read the question as "what if my admin user *is* compromised," the worst case for AWS.

Comment: MFA will prevent unauthorised access to the console. If somebody gets access to an EC2 instance, permissions will be limited to the IAM Role assigned.

Answer (score 0):

You could:

**Dump data to S3, then use glacier vault**

Dump your database using DB specific tools (eg, pgdump) and upload that file to an S3 bucket under your control. Then, move that data to a glacier Vault, and lock it. With Glacier Vault locks you can make it *impossible* to delete the files for a specific amount of time you chose. Not even the uber-admin of your account could do it. The only way this data gets lost if AWS itself gets compromised somehow. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/vault-lock.html#vault-lock-overview

As an alternative, you could try the new snapshots to S3 functionality https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ExportSnapshot.html in combination with the above technique. The drawback is that the data gets converted to Parquet, so I have no idea how easy it is to restore a database from that kind of snapshot.

**Copy snapshot to very restricted, backup only account**

Have a separate AWS account for backups, with severely restricted permissions, and copy the snapshots there: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_CopySnapshot.html

The "separate account" pattern was the way to go before glacier vault existed. But technically speaking, it is still under your responsibility to secure it - it's just much easier to do it properly this way.

Proper cross account permissions have to be set, so that you can copy snapshots to and from the backup account, but not delete them.